# Library/app for generating pdf reports php

Tags: web-apps, library, pdf, php

I'm looking for a good library (for PHP would be good) to generate PDF reports. The layout per page is exactly the same always, however, the data is changing per report and the number of pages will be different every time.

I've checked out FPDF and TCPDF, I was wondering if there was anything else out there thats a little more simple as my reports do not need to be fancy, just need to be dynamic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) the free server app allows you, *amongst many other things*, to fill pdf forms and output as pdf.

- Free (server and free versions)
- Pro is under $4
- Multi-platform
- Server version can be called from the command line or programmatically
- Fast
- Works
- Adobe not required.

*Note: I have no financial interest in the above software - I just **use** it*

Comment: Great, thank you for the recommendation. It seems like this may be the way to go. I am running off of Gentoo Linux and actually have it available in the distro.